# How do I get VLC on Ubuntu 18.04 to play mkv files

Tags: vlc, mkv, av1

When I try playing  an mkv file with vlc I get:
Codec not supported:
VLC could not decode the format "av01" (AOMedia's AV1 Video)

When I close the message the file actually plays only the sound track BUT NOT THE VIDEO.

How do I fix the problem.
Thank you folks for anyone who can help me.

Comment: Are `ubuntu-restricted-extras` installed?

Comment: I thought vlc used a built-in version of libdav1d for av1 decoding, if it did it isn't  anymore or in 3.08. You could rebuild vlc in the presence of libdav1-dev (avail. in a ppa) or use any snap version of vlc. Run `snap info vlc` to see available versions, I would not use the 4.x edge version, it's awful. For 3.08+ snap run `sudo snap install vlc --beta`  You can have both .deb and  snap vlc installed, the bigger vlc icon is the snap or go `snap run vlc` Alt. player that fully support av1 is mpv from a ppa.

Comment: Thank you Pilot6. I installed the ubuntu-restricted-extras but it made no difference.

Comment: Thank you doug. I installed snap vlc --beta and it solved the problem !

Comment: Have you found any solution at all for this? Even a converter would be nice